# Creating a drop-down effect with UIWebView and/or UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

In the mobile app for Wikipedia, they have a drop-down effect where if you click on the line, it opens up the content for that line and inserts it into the page. For example, lines might be Career, Business Life, and Personal Life, and if you click on, for example, the Career line, it inserts the content for Career between the the Career and Business Life lines. If you click on the Career line again, the Career content disappears and you are back to just the one line. I want my content to be in HTML format, so I am assuming that I need to do this with UIWebView somehow, probably in conjunction with UITableView. How would I create an effect like that?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use UIActionSheet....try something like...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"Take photo",@"Choose existing", nil];



            actionSheet.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

           [actionSheet showFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES]; //sender is the cell
```

also implement the action in the delegate method.....

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{



    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
    // blah blah
    }
else if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
    //sec index action... 
    }
}
```

you will get something like....
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The kind of flow you are talking about, people call it **Accordian**. Search for the term **iphone sdk accordion uitableview** in google you will have plenty of link available. You can  download a sample code [From Here](https://github.com/DekusDenial/UITableView-Accordion).